# grouping nodes with collapsible fieldset

Tags: nodes, entities

I use `entityreference` to link nodes to other nodes and `field_group` to display collapsible fieldsets with fields.

Assume I have node#1 which has a field `related_nodes` containing node#2, node#3 and node#4.

The display of this node looks like this:

```
node title

node body

related: 
- node#2
- node#3
- node#4
```

I can use `hook_node_view` to remove nodes from the `related_nodes` field on the fly using something like:

```
unset($node->content['field_info_case_law_references']['#items'][?]);
```

I want to remove all those nodes (e.g based on their title) and place them in groups, each in a collapsible fieldset within that `related:` field. so it ends up looking something like this:

```
node title

node body

related:
+ starting with A (collapsible fieldset)
  - node#2
+ starting with B (collapsible fieldset)
  - node#3
  - node#4
```

The default collapsible behaviour, html and styling of that I can configure from `admin/structure/types/manage/*/display` is good enough.

Where should I look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found it.

In the `HOOK_node_view` I can do:

```
if ($node->type=='CONTENT_TYPE') {

  // clone from a fieldset nearby
  $node->content['#fieldgroups']['group_FOO']=clone $node->content['#fieldgroups']['group_ORIG'];

  // modify fieldset
  $node->content['#fieldgroups']['group_FOO']->label="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  $node->content['#fieldgroups']['group_FOO']->weight=-1;
  $node->content['#fieldgroups']['group_FOO']->identifier=...
  $node->content['#fieldgroups']['group_FOO']->group_name=...

  // clone from a field nearby
  $node->content['field_FOO'] = $node->content['field_ORIG'];

  // modify field
  unset($node->content['field_FOO']['#items'][0]);
  unset($node->content['field_FOO']['#items'][1]);
  unset($node->content['field_FOO']['#items'][2]);

  // position fieldset and field
  $node->content['#group_children']['group_FOO'] = 'group_ORIG';
  $node->content['#group_children']['field_FOO'] = 'group_FOO';

}
```

[image]